# Kernel dies when processing DataFrame

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been able to get this to execute once but since then the kernel just hangs and then dies. Any help would be appreciated.

[Dataframe head]

[image: 1]

```
new_companies_df['Total Raised']= new_companies_df['Total Raised'].str.replace('$','')

#Program ref source:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-suffix-denomination-to-values/

#Initialize values dictionary
val_dict = {"M": 1000000, "B": 100000000,'K':1000,'None': 0}

result = []

for x in new_companies_df['Total Raised']:
   
 for key in val_dict:
        if key in value:
  
            # conversion of dictionary keys to values
            val = (x.replace(key, "")) * val_dict[key]
            result.append(val)

new_companies_df['Total Raised ($)'] = result

new_companies_df.head()
```

Comment: what's the size of your data frame? provide a miniamal dataframe data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using `.apply()` function from pandas directly with a custom function or a lambda expression. Something like this

```
def replace(x):
  val_dict = {"M": 1000000, "B": 100000000,'K':1000,'None': 0}

  for key in val_dict:
    if key in x:
      value = float(x.replace(key, ""))  # converting to float is important
      multiplier = float(val_dict[key])
      return value * multiplier

new_companies_df['Total Raised ($)']  = new_companies_df['Total Raised'].apply(replace)
```

I do not see any conversion to float. I suspect that your kernel died because you are multiplying strings with a large number which can get very nasty results. For example

```
"1" * 10 # this produces -> "1111111111"
1 * 10 # this produces -> 10
```

Comment: You are right, the onetime it worked it just infinitely reproduced the value . I also had trouble getting the float to compute  as the function kept throwing a cannot convert str to float even after removing the ‘$’.

Comment: Maybe you still have spaces in the string. Try using `.strip()` before converting to float. The best way will be to find a library that can convert the string (with $ and so on) to a number without you doing everything.

Comment: One additional step for the solution would be to use "0" rather than just ""  on Line 6 as the function still failed without this.

Comment: maybe you need to have 2 cases. 1 case with the value having "M", "B", etc in it, and the other case without. Should it be 0? Because it would convert anything that doesn't have "M", "B", etc in it to 0. E.g. $40000 -> $0 after the multiplication. I'd suggest 1, but it will depends on your use case :)